# Ubuntu detects Wacom tablet but I can't change the settings for it

Tags: 14.04, drivers, tablet, wacom

I want to use my Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch graphic tablet on my laptop which has Ubuntu 14.04 installed.

When I plug it in it gets detected and I can use it. But I have to change it to left handed mode to be able to use it correctly. Unfortunately I can't do that because Ubuntu won't let me.

When I open the settings for Wacom graphics tablet in the system settings is just says that it doesn't detect any graphic tablets.

How can I fix this? I don't even know where I should begin to look.